# Why Krishna advised Arjun to worship other Devas and attain powers?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

In Bhagwadgita, Krishna said to Arjun that if one worships other Devas, he will go to their Loka but who worships and surrenders unto him, will get united with him.

But when I read Mahabharat, I found that Krishna advised Arjun to please Siva for Pasupatastra. Similarly, Krishna advised Arjun to take blessings of Goddess before Mahabharat war.

I am a bit confused on this. When Krishna was himself with Arjun, why he needed Pasupatastra and other Astras from other Devas?